# How to remove the border/drop shadow from an UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I've been generating QR Codes using the **CIQRCodeGenerator** [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cifilter) and it works very well:

[image]

But when I resize the UIImageView and generate again

```
  @IBAction func sizeSliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    qrImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(sender.value), y: CGFloat(sender.value))
  }
```

I get a weird **Border/DropShadow** around the image sometimes:

[image]

**How can I prevent it from appearing at all times or remove it altogether?**

I have no idea what it is exactly, a border, a dropShadow or a Mask, as I'm new to Swift/iOS.

Thanks in advance!

PS. I didn't post any of the QR-Code generating code as it's pretty boilerplate and can be found in many tutorials out there, but let me know if you need it

EDIT:
`code to generate the QR Code Image`

```
private func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else {
      return nil
    }

    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage") 

    guard let qrEncodedImage = filter.outputImage else {
      return nil
    }

    let scaleX = qrImageView.frame.size.width / qrEncodedImage.extent.size.width
    let scaleY = qrImageView.frame.size.height / qrEncodedImage.extent.size.height
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY )

    if let outputImage = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
      return UIImage(ciImage: outputImage)
    }

    return nil
  }
```

`Code for button pressed`

```
  @IBAction func generateCodeButtonPressed(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    if codeTextField.text == "" {
      return
    }

    let newEncodedMessage = codeTextField.text!
    let encodedImage: UIImage = generateQRCode(from: newEncodedMessage)!
    qrImageView.image = encodedImage
    qrImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(sizeSlider.value), y: CGFloat(sizeSlider.value))


    qrImageView.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest
    qrImageView.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s a little hard to be sure without the code you’re using to generate the image for the image view, but that looks like a resizing artifact—the CIImage may be black or transparent outside the edges of the QR code, and when the image view size doesn’t match the image’s intended size, the edges get fuzzy and either the image-outside-its-boundaries or the image view’s background color start bleeding in. Might be able to fix it by setting the image view layer’s minification/magnification filters to “nearest neighbor”, like so:

```
imageView.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest
imageView.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest
```

---

Update from seeing the code you added—you’re currently resizing the image twice, first with the call to `applying(transform)` and then by setting a transform on the image view itself. I suspect the first resize is adding the blurriness, which the minification / magnification filter I suggested earlier then can’t fix. Try shortening `generateQRCode` to this:

```
private func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else {
        return nil
    }

    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    if let qrEncodedImage = filter.outputImage {
        return UIImage(cgImage: qrEncodedImage)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hello there, your solution didn't work, but I understand how it can be difficult to troubleshoot without looking at some code, I'm posting the code that I'm using to generate the Image as an Edit. Hope it helps! And thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: Ah—I think I see the issue now. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hello Noah, thank you for the answer. I must report that it didn't work. it's actually an issue with the scaleX and scaleY formula, if I set those to 20.0 the transform works perfectly every time, but obviously the idea is to avoid an arbitrary number altogether. Thank you very much nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you try to resize it to "non-square" (as your `scaleX` isn't always the same as `scaleY`), while the QR code is always square so both side should have the same scale factor to get a non-blurred image.

Something like:

```
let scaleX = qrImageView.frame.size.width / qrEncodedImage.extent.size.width
let scaleY = qrImageView.frame.size.height / qrEncodedImage.extent.size.height
let scale = max(scaleX, scaleY)
let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
```

will make sure you have "non-bordered/non-blurred/squared" `UIImage`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, believe it or not this problem remains after so long. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

I guess the issue is with the image(png) file not with your UIImageView. Try to use another image and I hope it will work!